# AheadWorks - Follow Up Email extension

Tags: extensions, email, quote

I'm using Follow Up Email extension from AheadWorks.
I tried to make a rule : **Abandoned cart**.

Here my Rule set:

### General:

Title               : Abandoned cart
Event               : New abandoned cart appeared
Cancellation events : - Order obtained 'Credit Card Verification' status
                      - Order obtained 'Processing' status
Email chain         : Send     : After 0 Days 0 Hours 30 Minutes
                      Template : AW Your cart has been abandoned_3.5.0

### Sender Details :

Sender name  : Andhi Irawan
Sender email : andi@bilna.com

### Send Test Email :

Test recipient : andi@bilna.com
Customer ID    : 77

### **Other values ​​are left as originally (default)**

AW Your cart has been abandoned_3.5.0 Newsletter template contained in the following line code:

```
{{foreach var="$quote.getAllVisibleItems()" template="nsltr:AW Abandoned cart row_3.5.0"}}
```

if the line code is not removed from the template then when I click the Save And Send Test Email button, the Mail Logs (Follow Up Email Queue) remains empty.

if the line code is removed then the Rule was to send an email to the Mail Logs. (see capture screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb3Pw.png) or
[image: Follow Up Email Queue]

but the table is empty in preview email
see capture screen here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK9rG.png or
[image: Empty Table in Email]

### the question is :

***how to display the content (product name, image, price) in the table on email***

Answer (score 2):

Please add the ID of the cart here: Rule Information => Send Test Email => Test object IDs. The details of this card will be displayed in the test email.